# running a jar in m2eeclipse

Tags: eclipse, m2e, spring-boot

Hi I am trying to do this tutorial from the Spring website.  http://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

I am getting an error running the final Jar file as a goal in Eclipse M2E.

I have a maven java core project. I successfully performed the 'clean package' command but after the jar got build I am not able to run it.  I confirmed if the jar is running fine from the dos command prompt by putting the jar in a different location (other than target folder) and it runs fine. What should i be doing to get the jar running as a Goal in M2E.

This is how i am running the jar in the maven build run configuration.

Goals:java -jar target/gs-rest-service-0.1.0.jar

the jar is in the target folder of the maven project.

Error:
Unable to parse command line options: Unrecognized option: -jar

usage: mvn [options] [] []

Options:
 -am,--also-make                        If project list is specified, also
                                        build projects required by the
                                        list
 -amd,--also-make-dependents.....

Answer (score 0):

"java -jar ..." is not a valid maven goal, so you at going at it the wrong way. Any reason not to just run the main method, since you are in eclipse already? If you prefer to use "java -jar" and don't want to use the normal command line then I believe you can have eclipse launch that process for you, but don't try and do it as a maven goal. Make sense?

Comment: Hi,  thank you for your reply and your time. Yes i can run the main method instead of running the jar but i wanted to know how to run the jar as a maven goal for my understanding of m2e.  I see   mvn clean package && java -jar target/gs-rest-service-0.1.0.jar is a valid maven goal but i am still getting error-  Unable to parse command line options: Unrecognized option: -jar.

Comment: also i can right click on the jar and run the jar by mentioning the main method in the run configuration in eclipse but i wanted to run it through maven.

Comment: The '&& java ...' bit is a shell command (nut a maven goal). I don't personally find m2e very useful for executing maven commands, but ymmv. How about "mvn spring-boot:run"?